# Extract data from System.Data.DataRow in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script that executes a SQL command and returns a list of ID numbers.

When I iterate through the list, this is what it returns.

```
System.Data.DataRow
System.Data.DataRow
System.Data.DataRow
System.Data.DataRow
System.Data.DataRow
System.Data.DataRow
```

I tried adding `Out-String` to my list,

```
$q_result = $db.ExecuteWithResults($int_cmd2)
$table = $q_result.Tables[0] | Out-String

foreach ($user_info in $table)
{
    write-host $user_info 
}
```

but that returns a poorly formatted list of numbers, everything is tabbed to the far right:

```
                                                                                                      GroupID
                                                                                                      -------------
                                                                                                                381
                                                                                                                382
                                                                                                                383
                                                                                                                384
                                                                                                                385
                                                                                                                386
```

I tried using, `$user_info.Item[0]` in the loop,  but that returns nothing.

How can I extract just the numbers from the list?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`Item` is a *parameterized property*, not a list you can index into:

```
foreach($row in $table)
{
    $row.Item("GroupID")
}
```

or (assuming that "GroupID" is the first column):

```
foreach($row in $table)
{
    $row.Item(0)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I got the `Item` Mixed up, it's listed as a property in the MSDN page.

Answer (score 33):

You can also use [ItemArray](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarow.itemarray). Prints the entire row, while Item(index) prints the values from the indexed cell.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the column name is GroupID

```
$sql = "SELECT [GroupID] FROM theTable"
$table = Invoke-SQLCmd -Query $sql -ServerInstance $sqlServerInstance -Database $database -OutputAs DataRows

foreach($user_info in $table)
{
    $user_info.GroupID
}
```

or

```
foreach($user_info in $table.GroupID)
{
    $user_info
}
```