# Iterate through each database on an instance using ForEach-Object in PowerShell does not work

Tags: sql-server, powershell, foreach, sqlcmd

I am new to PowerShell.
Trying to understand how to use `ForEach-Object` command to iterate through each database on a server.

However it only bring master database multiple times and doesn't seems to be iterating through the rest of them.

```
# generate list of databases to iterate through
$DB = Invoke-SqlCmd -ServerInstance databasecluster  -Database master -Query "SELECT [name] AS [Database] FROM sys.databases  ORDER BY 1 DESC;"
$Query = "select DB_name();"
$DB | ForEach-Object{
           $DB = "$_";
            Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $Query -ServerInstance myinstance;
}
```

What am I missing here?

**UPDATE**

```
PS C:\> $DB = Invoke-SqlCmd -ServerInstance myinstance -Database master -Query "SELECT [name] AS [Database] FROM sys.databases  ORDER BY 1 DESC;"
>> $Query = "select DB_name();"
>> $DB | ForEach-Object{
>>              $DB = "$_";
>>              Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance myinstance -Database $DB -Query $Query
>>   }
```

**Error**

```
*Invoke-Sqlcmd : Cannot open database "System.Data.DataRow" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'domain\username'.
At line:5 char:14
+ ...             Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance myinstance -Database $ ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], SqlException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlExceptionError,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand*
```

Comment: All `SELECT DB_NAME()` is going to return is the name of the database you connected to. If you want the names of all the databases on the instance have a look at `sys.databases`.

Comment: You don't specify a `-Database` parameter on your second `Invoke-SqlCmd` call, so it will be using whatever the default database of your login is... which is probably `master`.

Comment: Thanks. But now I have `System.Data.DataRow` error.  Running code on local, I can connect without supplying credentials, however error indicates `Login failed`

Comment: You'll have to check SQL Server's `ERRORLOG` file for the actual reason as to why the login failed. Unless your login is a member of sysadmins in SQL Server it's likely that it doesn't have access to all databases hosted by the instance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39224692/extract-data-from-system-data-datarow-in-powershell - The `$DB` object is an array of objects of types `System.Data.DataRow`. Try `$_.Database` (the name you gave the column in your query) to retrieve the values

Comment: @mjsqu Thank you! That was the trick. Please post the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Problem

The `$DB` object is an array of objects of types `System.Data.DataRow`. What is happening is the `$_` contains an entire `DataRow` from the query you issued:

```
SELECT [name] AS [Database] FROM sys.databases  ORDER BY 1 DESC;
```

When `$_` is specified in the `ForEach-Object` loop it just returns the type of the object as it has no default action, after all it is a row that could conceivably contain lots of values. You can see what happens by running these lines to address inspect the first 'row' in the `$DB` array:

```
# Just the DataRow
$DB[0]
# DB DataRow 1 column 1
$DB[0][0]
# DB First DataRow Database column
$DB[0].Database
```

#### Solution

The solution is to use `$_.Database` inside the loop to pick up the 'Database' column value from your query:

```
$DB = Invoke-SqlCmd -ServerInstance myinstance -Database master -Query "SELECT [name] AS [Database] FROM sys.databases  ORDER BY 1 DESC;"
$Query = "select DB_name();"
$DB | ForEach-Object{
             $DB = $_.Database;
             Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance myinstance -Database $DB -Query $Query
  }
```

#### Tip

It is also a good idea to use different variable names - re-using `$DB` inside a loop which commenced from `$DB |`  may work but it could get confusing in more complex scripts.